# Regex - Find all groups where you can find a given number

Tags: regex

I have a string such as this one :

```
:1-2-35:2-3-1:5-6-27456:35-2-11:9-5-6:1-5-2:
```

I'd like to get all the groups containing number `2`
The string is always composed of groups of 3 numbers with a dash between them.

So my regex would return this :

```
1 => :1-2-35:
2 => :2-3-1:
3 => :35-2-11:
4 => :1-5-2:
```

I've tried this with no success : `:\d*2-|-2-|2-\d*:`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: are they always single digits?

Comment: Forgot to mention it, numbers can be infinite ;)

Comment: Just 2, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this regex

```
[^:]*(?<=[-:])2(?=[-:])[^:]*
```

`[^:]` means match any character except `:`

`[^:]*` would match 0 to many characters except `:`

`2(?=[-:])` would match 2 only if it is followed by `-` or `:`

`(?<=[-:])2` would match 2 only it is preceded by `-` or `:`

**OR**

```
[^:]*\b2\b[^:]*
```

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking for, but could you tell me how it works please ? I'm not used to brackets and those kind of patterns.

Comment: This will much **any** number containing '2' (e.g. '20').

Comment: This doesn't include : characters at the end

Comment: I only want number 2, not number 20 :)

Comment: Wonderful ! Thank you very much ! (Could you add a quick explanation please?)

Comment: Nope that will match `12-3-3`

Comment: Thats Better albeit do you need to require beginning of string in the prefix match, example seems to indicate string always starts with `:` so you could use `(?<=-|:)`

Answer (score 0):

If the groups will always contain 3 number (and 2 dashes), you can use a regex like this:

```
:(2-\d+-\d+|\d+-2-\d+|\d+-\d+-2)(?=:)
```

(Note, it may vary slightly, based on the regex implementation of the language you are using.)

See, also, this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/tlM6fo)** in PHP.

Comment: The : from the preceding match will be missing from the following match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
(?<=:)(?:2-\d+-\d+|(?:\d+-){1,2}2\b[^:]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do the job

```
(?<=:)(?:2-\d+-\d+)|(?:\d+-2-\d+)|(?:\d+-\d+-2)(?=:)
```

The only limitation is whilst it filters on the `:` chars they are not included in the match.  If you try and include the `:` chars in the match then sequential matches will fail because the trailing `:` will already be gone for the beginning of the next match